# Should I use strings or constant integers to map properties? Does it make a difference?

Tags: javascript, performance, coding-style

Example of strings mapping properties:

```
var OPACITY = {
 "visible" : 10,
 "hidden : 0.1
}
```

How Ill be using it:

```
window.opacity = OPACITY["visible"]
```

Example of using constant integers instead:

```
const VISIBLE = 0
const HIDDEN = 1
var OPACITY = [10, 0.1];
```

How Ill be using it:

```
window.opacity = OPACITY[VISIBLE]
```

So I have two questions, which is more standard practice and does it make a difference in performance or reliability?

Comment: Array indexes are always treated as strings anyway. The answer to your question is that it makes no significant difference at all.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you’d be using these?

Comment: @Pointy Seriously? Reference?

Comment: @Mercado all object property names are strings. Arrays are objects.

Comment: Okay, but the array indices are shorter than the explicit strings. Do js engines somehow pre-process/cache/whatever these mappings so that it doesn't need to recompute the hash of the string key again to get its value?

Comment: With your example, you could just define `OPACITY_VISIBLE`. Presumably there will be more properties associated with `VISIBLE` and `HIDDEN`?

Comment: @Ryan, yes that was just an example

Comment: @Mercado: Well, the reason I asked for an example was to understand what more you’d be doing besides a static `OPACITY[VISIBLE]`. Anyway, just use the first option. If it becomes a performance problem, which it won’t, you can easily switch.

Comment: Yeah, I have already decided to use the first one. At this point, I'm just curious as to what's the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use constant integers, you'll never have to worry about having to make sure you cast your value to an integer to make it work.

As for performance? If your app is so loaded down it would impact performance, you have much, much bigger problems.

Comment: It absolutely doesn't matter because object property names (including array indexes) are always strings.

Comment: Well, I don't think that just because integers are treated as strings they don't pose a performance issue. I'm pretty sure Array can still perform better in terms of indexing. At this point, I'm just curious and have decided to use the first example where I use strings.